# What type is best to pass one React Component to another

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I want to pass some array of React Components to a React Component, I thought I could use the type `Component: React.ComponentClass<any> | React.StatelessComponent<any>` in props ([as per this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11944)), for example:

```js
interface Props {
  elements: (React.ComponentClass<any> | React.StatelessComponent<any>)[];
}

const App = (props: Props) => (
  <>
    {props.elements.map(X => <X />)}
  </>
)
```

But when following this pattern, I get the following error:

> Element type 'X' does not have any construct or call signatures

Ok, sure; it needs to be a function, so maybe:

```js
interface Props {
  elements: (() => (React.ComponentClass<any> | React.StatelessComponent<any>))[];
}
```

But then I am told that this type is missing properties `type`, `key`, and `props`.

My question is, what type should I use in this situation?

---

Going with the type

```js
(() => React.ReactElement)[]
```

Seems to remove any errors, but is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually an even better type is React.ReactNode, that is:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;

(React.ReactElement is part of ReactChild).
```

Basically React.ReactNode is anything that can be rendered inside jsx:

```
const TestApp: React.FunctionComponent<{ elements: Array<React.ReactNode> }> = props => {
    return <>{...props.elements}</>;
};
```

You should also look at reacts child props. That can be used to compose elements like writing plain HTML:

```
<Test>
  <Component1 />
  <Component1 />
</Test>
```

And your test component would be:

```
const TestApp: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
    return <>{...props.children}</>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good; I am aware of children, but it doesn't really work if you want to pass this in multiple times,and it can sometimes be a little confusing (imo)

Comment: yeah I agree about that. This blog here also has some neat ideas: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-children-composition-patterns-with-typescript-56dfc8923c64 (open in incognito if medium tries to paywall you)